# Vuejs prevent data to be null

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

In my component I've data that is succesptible to be invalid

```
<template>
  <p> field </p>
  <p> {{ maybeInvalid }} </p>
  <p> other field </p>
<template>

var component = {
  data: function () {
    return {
      maybeInvalid: xxx
  }
}
```

I've 3 ideas to fix that :

1 - Use `v-if` `v-else` in template

```
<template>
  <p> field </p>
  <p v-if="isValid(maybeInvalid)"> {{ maybeInvalid }} </p>
  <p v-else> invalid </p>
  <p> other field </p>
<template>

...
methods: {
  isValid: function (data) {
    return data != null;
  }
}
```

2 - Make a computed value

```
<template>
  <p> field </p>
  <p> {{ computedIsValid }} </p>
  <p> other field </p>
<template>

computed: {
  computedIsValid: function() {
    return isValid(maybeInvalid) ? maybeInvalid : "invalid";
  }
}
```

3 - build a component

```
var isValidCompoenent = {
  props: ['maybeInvalid'],

  template: `
    <p v-if="isValid(maybeInvalid)"> {{ maybeInvalid }} </p>
    <p v-else> invalid </p>`

  methods: {
    isValid: function (data) {
      return data != null;
    }
  }
}
```

and use this component

```
<template>
  <p> field </p>
  <is-valid-component :maybeInvalid="maybeInvalid" /> 
  <p> other field </p>
<template>

... 
components: {
  isValidComponent: isValidComponent
}
```

I would like to know what's the best (more idiomatic) solution to solve that pattern

Thanks

Comment: You can also use directive) Component looks like sugar for computed, u can replace method by computed property in it. If u often need to check isvalid, it is better to choose component, otherwise computed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to choose which would be more idiomatic; these are all idiomatic solutions to your issue using Vue. In other words, I would not be unhappy to see any of them in a Vue application.

That said, I would steer away from the component solution in this case **unless** you are likely to use the `is-valid` component in *many* places, not just the one component you are talking about here. Additionally, Joe Developer reading your code is not going to know right off the bat exactly what that does; they'll have to go read the code for `is-valid`.

Using a computed or a `v-if` are pretty much equivalent in my eyes in this case with one exception. Using the same argument above, Joe Developer reading your template is going to immediately know what happens with `v-if` but will have to look at the computed to fully understand it. This, *however* is a *very* minor thing.